# auto run js check user name availability after user has stopped typing just doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, timer, keydown

I have combined itechroom checkUserName function 
with JohnP's run js after user finished typing function
but it doesn't seem to work...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //JohnyP keydowntimer
    var timer = null;
    $('#username').keydown(function(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(checkUserName(usercheck), 1000);
    });

    //http://www.itechroom.com
    function checkUserName(usercheck){
            $('#usercheck').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
            $.post("checkuser.php", {username: usercheck} , function(data){
                if (data != '' || data != undefined || data != null){
                    $('#usercheck').html(data);
                }
            });
    }
})
```

I've tried `onblur="checkUserName(this.value)"` and it worked well...

Comment: just a tip, you can universally set up JQuery to display/remove the ajax loader whenever any ajax call is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you're declaring `usercheck` anywhere (or, at least, aren't setting its value within the snippet). What seems to be missing is...

```
$('#username').keydown(function () {
    var usercheck = $(this).val(); // ...this line.
    // etc.
});
```

But, you also have an issue with `setTimeout`. As it stands, `checkUserName(usercheck)` is being called immediately and the return value is then being passed to `setTimeout`.

Since you need to pass an argument, you can wrap the call to `checkUserName` in a new function which will be called when the timeout expires and will in turn call `checkUserName`:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    checkUserName(usercheck);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not set a value for the variable `usercheck` anywhere... would be my first guess.